# How to auto connect to wifi in coffee shop with bash script

Tags: bash, wifi-hotspot

I'm using Arch and bash and Openbox and everything is upto date.

Hopefully this will help a few people

I'm often in Starbucks.

The method to connect is to their free wifi in the Uk is to

1. Connect to the Starbucks hotspot
2. Open a browser. Sometimes, but not always, the browser auto re-directs to https://wifi.splash-access.com where there is a green "Accept and connect" button. You press this and it indicates successful connection, if it connects, but it does not always sucessfully connect.   This url also produces the connection page with the "accept and connect" button https://wifi.splash-access.com/accounts/starbucks/index.asp?e=1&baseurl=https://n401.network-auth.com/splash/grant&theurl=https://www.starbucks.co.uk/&Res=&duration=360&node_id=149624927815612&node_mac=88:15:44:ac:07:bc&client_ip=10.129.124.42&client_mac=e8:b1:fc:85:7a:69&c=y23m4d&email=info@splashaccess.co.uk&fname=Splash&lname=Access&SOffer=

I could use `xdotool` to press this connect button, but for various screen config reasons my browser size / location changes and also the starbucks button seems to move.

In any case doing this fully with a script and `curl` or other tools means a good deal less messing around.

Can anyone suggest how I can push this button with a script, or otherwise connect with a  script. 5G mobile data is useless in this location or I would just use that.

Here is what I have so far

```
# show what we are doing with a popup
yad --title='#StarbucksWifi.. connecting' --undecorated --no-buttons --text-align=center --on-top --no-focus --text='Connecting to\n\n#StarbucksWifi\n' --timeout=3 &

# connect to starbucks SSID
nmcli -t con up id '#StarbucksWifi' >/dev/null 2>&1 & sleep 5;

# wait until this has completed
wait

# get SSID connection status for this SSID
SSID_connection_status="$(nmcli connection show | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')"

# show if we are connected
yad --timeout=2 --text="connected to - $SSID_connection status"
```

## Additional efforts

**This command:**
links https://wifi.splash-access.com/accounts/starbucks/index.asp?e=1&baseurl=https://n401.network-auth.com/splash/grant&theurl=https://www.starbucks.co.uk/&Res=&duration=360&node_id=149624927815612&node_mac=88:15:44:ac:07:bc&client_ip=10.129.124.42&client_mac=e8:b1:fc:85:7a:69&c=y23m4d&email=info@splashaccess.co.uk&fname=Splash&lname=Access&SOffer=

**Produces this output**
[1] 1080117
[2] 1080118
[3] 1080119
[4] 1080120
[5] 1080121
[6] 1080122
[7] 1080123
[8] 1080124
[9] 1080125
[10] 1080126
[11] 1080127
[12] 1080128
[13] 1080129
[2]   Done                    baseurl=https://n401.network-auth.com/splash/grant
[5]   Done                    duration=360
[6]   Done                    node_id=149624927815612
[7]   Done                    node_mac=88:15:44:ac:07:bc
[9]   Done                    client_mac=e8:b1:fc:85:7a:69
[10]   Done                    c=y23m4d
[11]   Done                    email=info@splashaccess.co.uk

**same command run again**
links https://wifi.splash-access.com/accounts/starbucks/index.asp?e=1&baseurl=https://n401.network-auth.com/splash/grant&theurl=https://www.starbucks.co.uk/&Res=&duration=360&node_id=149624927815612&node_mac=88:15:44:ac:07:bc&client_ip=10.129.124.42&client_mac=e8:b1:fc:85:7a:69&c=y23m4d&email=info@splashaccess.co.uk&fname=Splash&lname=Access&SOffer=

**Produces even more output**
[14] 1080854
[15] 1080855
[16] 1080856
[17] 1080857
[18] 1080858
[19] 1080859
[20] 1080860
[21] 1080861
[22] 1080862
[23] 1080863
[24] 1080864
[25] 1080865
[26] 1080866

[1]+  Stopped                 links https://wifi.splash-access.com/accounts/starbucks/index.asp?e=1
[3]   Done                    theurl=https://www.starbucks.co.uk/
[4]   Done                    Res=
[8]   Done                    client_ip=10.129.124.42
[12]   Done                    fname=Splash
[13]   Done                    lname=Access
[15]   Done                    baseurl=https://n401.network-auth.com/splash/grant
[16]   Done                    theurl=https://www.starbucks.co.uk/
[17]   Done                    Res=
[18]   Done                    duration=360
[19]   Done                    node_id=149624927815612
[20]   Done                    node_mac=88:15:44:ac:07:bc
[21]   Done                    client_ip=10.129.124.42
[22]   Done                    client_mac=e8:b1:fc:85:7a:69
[23]   Done                    c=y23m4d
[24]   Done                    email=info@splashaccess.co.uk

Comment: If you can click the button using the text browsers `links` or `lynx` I believe it will be easier to solve. Can you test that?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Lynx is flashing through a few urls when I pres the connect button. The `p` command in `lynx` when the ' accept and connect' button is selected does not reveal a specific connection link as I had hoped. Rather it just shows the same https://wifi.splash-access.com link. I will see tomorrow if I can work out how to capture the links that `lynx` is flashnig through. It's moving through them to rapidly to see. If I can't capture these I will try filming this and slowing the movie down.

Comment: I've added more experimental output to original post at the bottom under `Additional efforts`

Comment: `links` shows the link for the "accept and connect" button as `https://wifi.splash-access.com/accounts/starbucks/chkemail.php`. Connection with this link looks to be seemless with links. However I am already connected, so that is not certian. certianly slick c.f. `Firefox`. I will check this link with `links` when I next have to login. either tomorrow or over the next few days. There seems to be no way to logout to test. Can I call `links` headless and press the button from a script?

Comment: If you change you mac addr (`macchanger`) I think you have to login again.

Comment: I did all this from one laptop. I didn't change device. There are two macs.  The hotspot associated mac `node_mac=88:15:44:ac:07:bc` and my device mac `client_mac=e8:b1:fc:85:7a:69`

Comment: In any case, whoever came up with this business of Web login before you can use Wi-Fi should be put in front of a firing squad.

Comment: Does anyone know how to disconnect from the uk starbucks hot spot after connecting, so that I can run more connection tests? There is no logout / logoff button anywhere that I can see. There seems to be no means to logout. I'd rather not clear browser cache because I'm going to have to re-log back into all the sites I use regularly, of which there are many

Comment: @ole-tange thanks for the `macchanger` hint. I may use that to see if it gives me more login attempts, using a new mac address `macchanger -r wlp3s0` will reassign my wi-fi interface a random new mac.

Answer (score -1):

The WiFi login API undoubtedly has bot protection, which is probably disabled by a java applet when you click the button in the browser. If you examine the source for that web page, you can find the script name, and run it from your bash script, with `java -jar`.

Comment: thanks, the button does sit behind a javascript. I will try saving it when I am next in the coffee shop and see if I can run it as you suggest. From memory it has no network pointers within it so if I ran it from my laptop with `java -jar connection-script.js` I don't think it would do anything. Nevertheless I will have another look. Thanks

Comment: java applets haven't been a thing you could run in browsers reliably since 2017, when the last browsers stopped supporting them. So, this is pretty far off the mark, as starbucks IT is centrally managed and its access points are definitely not something that hasn't been updated since 2015!